# Парсинг строки Visual Basic

Tags: строки, visual-basic

Имея строку

```
"Country": "Россия",
        "Email": "dfhdf@mail.ru",
        "ExtraParameters": [],
        "Gender": "Женский",
        "GivenName": "Анастасия",
        "Id": "fd978916-9a89-4621-a1ee-5bc718eead90",
        "MiddleName": "",
        "Name": "Иванова Анастасия ",
        "NeedEmailConfirmation": true,
        "NeedPhoneConfirmation": false,
        "Phone": "79832654360",
        "Surname": "Иванова",
        "Username": "dfhdf@mail.ru"
```

Как в другую строку поместить параметр Id

Comment: Строка где (*Excel, Word*)? В строке есть символ переноса текста или текст так показан для удобочитаемости? *ID* перенести выше/ниже или вообще вырезать из текста? Если вырезать: добавить в другому тексту или создать новую строку?

Comment: Visual Basic!!!

Comment: Понял. без *Application*... извините.